# how to speed up es match query performance

Tags: elasticsearch

There is a company index with many records

```
health status index               uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
green  open   company             KTngnM6ASD-_KdU0FFAWRA   1   0   95185696     31780899     26.5gb         26.5gb
```

when execute match query

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": {
        "query": "some Chinese com name",
        "operator": "and"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

if use `and` operator sometimes cannot find any result (because not all word hit), but use `or` it takes more time

e.g. search some words `and` took `3446` but `or` took `23650`

If use `or` how to  speed up response performance?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like your system is seriously undersized for your index. Consider [upgrading your machine](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-for-search-speed.html#_use_faster_hardware_2), especially memory and use SSDs. Such simple queries should not take over 400-500ms. Sounds like your waiting for IO. If you have enough memory to fit the index, you can run some [warm up queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-for-search-speed.html#_warm_up_the_filesystem_cache) to load it into memory and do fast searches on it. You can also add more nodes to your cluster and increase the [shard and replica count](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-for-search-speed.html#_replicas_might_help_with_throughput_but_not_always) to split the load on these nodes.

If you are not in a position to upgrade the system, you can try to add some [filters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) to your query to limit the number of documents that are matched. This should also speed up your query time.